# Python class able to be mapped by QDataWidgetMapper

Tags: python, c++

I have a c++ class that I want to 'translate' in Python.
In c++ the instances of my class are mapped by a QDataWidgetMapper, works fine.
But I can't make it work in Python.
Here is my class, in C++  and in Python.

This is the header file:

```
#ifndef OPTIONGROUP_H
#define OPTIONGROUP_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QMap>

class QRadioButton;

class OptionGroup : public QWidget
{
Q_OBJECT
Q_PROPERTY(int currentSelection READ currentSelection WRITE setCurrentSelection USER true)

public:
explicit OptionGroup(QWidget *parent = 0);
int currentSelection() const;
void setCurrentSelection(int selection);
void setSelectionId(QRadioButton *button, int id);
void OptionGroup::clear();

signals:
void selectionChanged(int selection);

public slots:
void buttonToggled(bool checked);

private:
int currentSelection_;
QMap<int, QRadioButton*> buttonMap_;
QMap<QRadioButton*, int> revButtonMap_;
};

#endif // OPTIONGROUP_H
```

This is the source file:

```
#include <QRadioButton>
#include "optiongroup.h"
#include <qdebug.h>

OptionGroup::OptionGroup(QWidget *parent) :QWidget(parent), currentSelection_(-1)
{
    qDebug()<<"1.OptionGroup: currentSelection_=" << currentSelection_;
}

int OptionGroup::currentSelection() const
{ return currentSelection_; }

void OptionGroup::setCurrentSelection(int selection)
{    
    // If the specified selection id is not in our button map,
    // then it is invalid, set selection to -1. Otherwise,
    // update the selection to user specified value
    qDebug()<<"1.setCurrentSelection: selection=" <<selection;
    auto iter = buttonMap_.find(selection);
    qDebug() << "2.setCurrentSelection: iter=" << iter.value() ;
    if (iter == buttonMap_.end() || selection < 0) {
        currentSelection_ = -1;
        for (iter = buttonMap_.begin(); iter != buttonMap_.end(); ++iter)
            iter.value()->setChecked(false);
    } else {
        iter.value()->setChecked(true);
        currentSelection_ = selection;
    }
}

void OptionGroup::setSelectionId(QRadioButton* button, int id)
{
    // Make sure we got a valid Id (non-negative)
    // Also then listen for signals from this button
    qDebug()<<"1.setSelectionId: button=" <<button->objectName() << " id=" << id;
    if (id >= 0) {
        buttonMap_[id] = button;
        revButtonMap_[button] = id;
        connect(button, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)), this, SLOT(buttonToggled(bool)));
    }
}

void OptionGroup::buttonToggled(bool checked)
{
    qDebug()<<"1.buttonToggled: checked=" <<checked;
    if (checked == true) {
        QRadioButton* btn = qobject_cast<QRadioButton*>(sender());
        Q_ASSERT(btn);
        currentSelection_ = revButtonMap_[btn];
        emit selectionChanged(currentSelection_);
    }
}

void OptionGroup::clear()
{
    qDebug() << "1.clear";
    foreach (QRadioButton *RadioButton, buttonMap_){
        RadioButton->setAutoExclusive(false);
        RadioButton->setChecked(false);
        RadioButton->setAutoExclusive(true);
    }
    currentSelection_ = false;
    qDebug() << "2.clear  emit selectionChanged";
    emit selectionChanged(currentSelection_);
}
```

PYTHON:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt4.QtCore import QObject, SIGNAL, SLOT, pyqtProperty, pyqtSignal, QPoint, qDebug
from PyQt4.QtGui import QRadioButton


class QMap(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        self = []
        pass
    def find(self, item):
        return self[item]        
    def begin(self):
        return 0
    def end(self):
        return len(self)




class OptionGroup(QtGui.QWidget) :
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(OptionGroup, self).__init__(parent)
        self.currentSelection_ = -1
        print("1.OptionGroup: currentSelection_=", self.currentSelection_)
        self.buttonMap_ = QMap()
        self.revButtonMap_ = QMap()
    def currentSelection(self):
        return self.currentSelection_
    def setCurrentSelection(self, selection):
        # If the specified selection id is not in our button map,
        # then it is invalid, set selection to -1. Otherwise,
        # update the selection to user specified value
        print("1.setCurrentSelection: selection=" ,selection)
        iter = self.buttonMap_.find(selection)
        print("2.setCurrentSelection: iter=", iter.value())
        if (iter == self.buttonMap_.end() or selection < 0):
            self.currentSelection_ = -1
            for iter in range(self.buttonMap_.begin(), self.buttonMap_.end()):
                iter.setChecked(False);
        else:
            iter.setChecked(True)
            self.currentSelection_ = selection

    currentSelection = pyqtProperty(int, currentSelection, setCurrentSelection)



    def setSelectionId(self, button, id):
        # Make sure we got a valid Id (non-negative)
        # Also then listen for signals from this button
        print("1.setSelectionId: button=", button.objectName(), " id=", id)

        if id >= 0:
            self.buttonMap_[id] = button
            self.revButtonMap_[button] = id
            QObject.connect(button, SIGNAL('toggled(bool)'), self.buttonToggled)
    def buttonToggled(self, checked):
        btn = self.sender()        
        print("1.buttonToggled: checked=", btn.checked)
        if btn.isChecked() == True:            
            self.currentSelection_ = self.revButtonMap_[btn]            
            self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("selectionChanged"), self.currentSelection_)
    def clear(self):
        print("1.clear")
        for key, RadioButton in self.buttonMap_.items():            
            RadioButton.setAutoExclusive(False)
            RadioButton.setChecked(False)
            RadioButton.setAutoExclusive(True)

        self.currentSelection_ = False
        print("2.clear  emit selectionChanged")
        self.emit(SIGNAL('selectionChanged'), self.currentSelection_)
```

(in Python version I 've created a custom QMap class as it doesn't exist in Python 3.4 that I 'm using)

What have I done wrong and my Python class doesn't work like the C++ one?
(is not properly mapped by QDataWidgetMapper, so it doesn't display data from my database)

Answer (score 0):

Answering to my self, the solution was incredibly simple:

I changed

```
currentSelection = pyqtProperty(int, currentSelection, setCurrentSelection)
```

...to:

```
currentSelection = pyqtProperty(int, currentSelection, setCurrentSelection, user = True)
```